# JavaFX Mac M1 errors

Tags: eclipse, macos, javafx, scenebuilder, apple-silicon

I'am using JavaFX and SceneBuilder on Eclipse.

**Here is my setup :**

Installing the aarch64 in 19.0.2.1 for Mac here :

- https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path and I added the following .jar in the module path.

[image: path]

Main -> Run As -> Run configurations

I added this in the VM arguments :

```
--module-path /Users/hicham/Desktop/javafx-sdk-19.0.2-2.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

I didn't understand how to config the link with the SceneBuilder so it doesn't open any window but it runs the program (with the same errors than bellow)

So I tried to run a lambda program with setuping IntelliJ IDEA.
The Program works and a window with the "hello" button given by the demo JavaFX project works.

But I get the same errors I got on Eclipse.
These are the errors :

```
1   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e9b6d4c _ZN15MenuBarInstance21IsAutoShowHideAllowedEv + 284
2   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e890230 _ZN15MenuBarInstance24UpdateAutoShowVisibilityE5Pointh + 40
3   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e894380 _ZL19AutoShowHideHandlerP25OpaqueEventHandlerCallRefP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 104
4   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e7f44c0 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1092
5   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e7f3940 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 356
6   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e7f37d0 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 44
7   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e8339cc _ZL29ToolboxEventDispatcherHandlerP25OpaqueEventHandlerCallRefP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 472
8   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e7f4968 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 2284
9   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e7f3940 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 356
10  HIToolbox                           0x000000018e809bb8 SendEventToEventTarget + 40
11  AppKit                              0x00000001883c7ad8 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2044
12  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c8df8 +[GlassApplication enterNestedEventLoopWithEnv:] + 232
13  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c985c Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacApplication__1enterNestedEventLoopImpl + 64
14  ???                                 0x000000010a92d8ac 0x0 + 4472363180
15  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
16  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
17  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
18  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
19  ???                                 0x000000010a929fc8 0x0 + 4472348616
20  ???                                 0x000000010a929fc8 0x0 + 4472348616
21  ???                                 0x000000010a924140 0x0 + 4472324416
22  libjvm.dylib                        0x0000000102323270 _ZN9JavaCalls11call_helperEP9JavaValueRK12methodHandleP17JavaCallArgumentsP10JavaThread + 908
23  libjvm.dylib                        0x000000010237f088 _ZL20jni_invoke_nonstaticP7JNIEnv_P9JavaValueP8_jobject11JNICallTypeP10_jmethodIDP18JNI_ArgumentPusherP10JavaThread + 796
24  libjvm.dylib                        0x0000000102383764 jni_CallVoidMethod + 312
25  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c6d94 -[GlassApplication applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 440
26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018513d570 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001851db054 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88
28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001851daf9c _CFXRegistrationPost + 440
29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018510eb74 _CFXNotificationPost + 708
30  Foundation                          0x0000000185ffc72c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 88
31  AppKit                              0x00000001883bbc24 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 248
32  AppKit                              0x00000001883bb910 -[NSApplication run] + 252
33  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c8be0 -[GlassApplication runLoop:] + 1996
34  Foundation                          0x000000018606cb30 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 264
35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185148a18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
36  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001851489ac __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018514871c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185147320 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
39  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185146888 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
40  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000100e72fec CreateExecutionEnvironment + 400
41  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000100e6f1fc JLI_Launch + 1184
42  java                                0x0000000100dbbbb0 main + 408
43  dyld                                0x0000000184d3fe50 start + 2544
1   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e8905c8 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 120
2   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e83327c SetMenuBarObscured + 224
3   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e832ee8 _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 172
4   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e82cfcc _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 296
5   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e7f3cd0 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 176
6   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e82c96c AcquireEventFromQueue + 432
7   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e81bc84 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 320
8   HIToolbox                           0x000000018e81bb2c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
9   AppKit                              0x00000001883c8424 _DPSNextEvent + 632
10  AppKit                              0x00000001883c75b4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 728
11  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c8df8 +[GlassApplication enterNestedEventLoopWithEnv:] + 232
12  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c985c Java_com_sun_glass_ui_mac_MacApplication__1enterNestedEventLoopImpl + 64
13  ???                                 0x000000010a92d8ac 0x0 + 4472363180
14  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
15  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
16  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
17  ???                                 0x000000010a929d80 0x0 + 4472348032
18  ???                                 0x000000010a929fc8 0x0 + 4472348616
19  ???                                 0x000000010a929fc8 0x0 + 4472348616
20  ???                                 0x000000010a924140 0x0 + 4472324416
21  libjvm.dylib                        0x0000000102323270 _ZN9JavaCalls11call_helperEP9JavaValueRK12methodHandleP17JavaCallArgumentsP10JavaThread + 908
22  libjvm.dylib                        0x000000010237f088 _ZL20jni_invoke_nonstaticP7JNIEnv_P9JavaValueP8_jobject11JNICallTypeP10_jmethodIDP18JNI_ArgumentPusherP10JavaThread + 796
23  libjvm.dylib                        0x0000000102383764 jni_CallVoidMethod + 312
24  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c6d94 -[GlassApplication applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 440
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018513d570 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001851db054 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001851daf9c _CFXRegistrationPost + 440
28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018510eb74 _CFXNotificationPost + 708
29  Foundation                          0x0000000185ffc72c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 88
30  AppKit                              0x00000001883bbc24 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 248
31  AppKit                              0x00000001883bb910 -[NSApplication run] + 252
32  libglass.dylib                      0x00000001205c8be0 -[GlassApplication runLoop:] + 1996
33  Foundation                          0x000000018606cb30 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 264
34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185148a18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
35  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001851489ac __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018514871c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
37  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185147320 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185146888 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
39  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000100e72fec CreateExecutionEnvironment + 400
40  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000100e6f1fc JLI_Launch + 1184
41  java                                0x0000000100dbbbb0 main + 408
42  dyld                                0x0000000184d3fe50 start + 2544
```

I went on a few forums but I didn't find any solutions.
Do someone have a solution ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Try using the most recent version of the JDK/JRE (I don't know if this will help, but if there were any M1 issues fixed in recent Java versions, you would pick up those fixes).

Comment: What is a "lambda program"?

Comment: Why does the module path have both individual JavaFX jars listed and a separate entry for "JavaFX SDK"?  What is in the "JavaFX SDK" entry?

Comment: You said that you also used Idea.  When you exactly follow the instructions for the [New JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), do you get the same output?  Maybe you already did this, but it wasn't clear to me from the question exactly what you did in Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not answering earlier.

I found the solution, the following errors are due to the "Menu Bar" on my Macbook which was hidden.

1. Click the Apple icon and select System Settings.
2. Select Desktop & Dock.
3. Scroll down to the Menu Bar heading and from here, click the
   drop-down next to Automatically hide and show the menu bar.
4. Select Never.

Please note that these errors do not cause a crash. 
That is why I was be able to run the application on IntelliJ Idea.

Thank you for replying and correcting me.